# How to deal with record datatype in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to extract a value from a RECORD datatype field in my GBQ table. Could someone share your thoughts about how to extract a value from a field which is of RECORD datatype? Here is what I have tried so far.

**xyz** - a field which is of RECORD datatype.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE xyz.key = 'some_value'
```

Comment: Please provide more data: what error do you get when you run the query? Can you provide the exact query text you use? The schema of the table may be helpful too. Thank you.

Comment: I am having some data in BQ and trying to write a SQL on top of it but I get an error when I query on RECORD column.

Comment: "an error" -> can you be more explicit please?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(xyz, r'"key":"(.*?)"')
```

For further study go through,

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#regexp_extract